# Webservice error in Apex

Tags: apex, soap-api, callout, wsdl

I have generated classes from WSDL file. I'm trying to execute a method 
from the generated class, there I'm getting the below error.

> System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: Unexpected
>   element. Parser was expecting element
>   'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/:Envelope' but found ':html'

What can I change to avoid the error?

Comment: You can try to fix your class according to your endpoint specifications

Comment: Your server is returning an error page, in HTML. You'll want to use something like [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/) to diagnose the issue.

Comment: @sfdcfox OK,I'll check

Comment: Another option would be to use Assertible (https://assertible.com) or Postman (https://getpostman.com) to debug the issues. Both are free to use and similar to SoapUI, but a little more modern (I am a founder at Assertible. Good luck!).

Comment: @RockSFDC If you are in a debug org, check for the CALLOUT_REQUEST and CALLOUT_RESPONSE pair in the debug log. You might be able to see the problem response there.

Answer (score 2):

This occurs when the external service didn't return a SOAP response. In this case, rather than a SOAP `envelope` element there is an `html` element at the start of the response.

As @sfdcfox commented, this indicates the service is returning an HTML response. It's likely some sort of error page, security response, or a redirect.

In a Salesforce Debug org you can check the Apex debug log for the `CALLOUT_REQUEST` and `CALLOUT_RESPONSE` pair. The latter should show you exactly what is coming back.

Comment: Troubleshooting a similar error. For what it's worth, I have the Callout category on my debug level set to "FINEST", and I don't see any CALLOUT_RESPONSE in my logs.

Comment: @MatthewSouther The CALLOUT_RESPONSE won't appear in production orgs. Try making the callout from a developer edition org.